# Arrange/sort data in pandas dataframe data based on column

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I am new to Pandas.  I need to sort and group data values in descending order based on cyclic order within groups.  I have the below dataframe:

```
Col1 Col2  
A     5030 
B     4250
c     3340
D     2100
A     5044
B     4790
C     3482
C     3233
A      5099
B      4820
D      2345
D      2784
A      5999
```

I need to sort the dataframe so that all the values in `Col2` are arranged within `Col1` in a cyclic order based on highest to lowest. For example, all the highest values of (A, B, C, D) will be ordered first and then the second highest values of (A, B, C, D) needs be follow and then the 3rd highest values of (A, B, C, D) group needs to follow and so on.

The final dataframe should look like this after the sorting:

```
Col1     Col2

A         5999
B         4820
C         3482
D         2784
A         5099
B         4790
C         3340
D         2345
A         5044
B         4250
C         3233
D         2100
A         5030
```

`Col1` will not have any other values apart from (A, B, C, D). But there may be scenarios when only 2 or 3 distinct values are present in `Col1`. So the logic needs to be made accordingly.

I could solve the problem by following steps:

1. Create  separated dataframes based on distinct values in `Col1`.
2. Ordering and Indexing each of the sub-dataframes in descending order  based on values in `Col2`.
3. Then looping through the indexes of the sub-datraframe and appending the data in a new dataframe from each individual sub-datframe.

This process does not seem to be the best approach. So I am looking for suggestions for a simpler native solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC create new key using `cumcount`

```
df['Key']=df.sort_values('Col2',ascending=False).groupby('Col1').cumcount()
df=df.sort_values(['Key','Col1']).drop('Key',1)
df
Out[453]: 
   Col1  Col2
12    A  5999
9     B  4820
6     C  3482
11    D  2784
8     A  5099
5     B  4790
2     C  3340
10    D  2345
4     A  5044
1     B  4250
7     C  3233
3     D  2100
0     A  5030
```

Comment: Awesome .Thank You :)  ..Also  , a special shoutout for formatting my Question first .

Comment: @user2717470 yw :-) happy coding and if this help would you like accept >?

Comment: Sure  .I have accepted the answer  .Thanks for the super quick response